# How to import data from a .env file in TypeScript project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, environment-variables

I want to build sanity studio (sanity.io), in the studio root folder, there is a file, that is `sanity.config.ts` which is:

```
import {createConfig} from 'sanity';
import {deskTool} from 'sanity/desk';
import {schemaTypes} from './schemas';
import { markdownSchema } from 'sanity-plugin-markdown';

export default createConfig({
  name: 'default',
  title: 'dev-portfolio',

  projectId: 'lda05mbj',
  dataset: 'production',

  plugins: [deskTool(), markdownSchema()],

  schema: {
    types: schemaTypes,
  },
})
```

I want to import the **projectId** & **dataset** from a `.env` file, how I can do that? I create a `.env` file that is:

```
SANITY_PROJECT_ID=lda05mbj
SANITY_DATASET=production
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You have to prefix your environment variables with `SANITY_STUDIO_` else it won't be included in the javaScript bundle.
https://www.sanity.io/docs/studio-environment-variables#f5e9e3158896

Comment: Same issue. not recognised by editor :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to prefix your environment variables with `SANITY_STUDIO_`. Environment variables that are prefixed with `SANITY_STUDIO_` will be available inside the javascript bundle and can be accessed from code as `process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_YOUR_ENV_VAR`.

Comment: From the other answer it seems that Sanity Studio projects already have access to `dotenv`

Comment: Yes. you are right.